# ZeroMQ pattern Proxy (Router / Router) does not connect Front with Back or Back with Front

Tags: node.js, typescript, sockets, zeromq

I am practicing with the ZeroMQ module to create Socket but I am having a problem with the Proxy pattern (Router / Router), I have been able to verify that the Client connects well with the Front and the Worker with the Back but when it arrives to send the message of the Front to Back or vice versa is not sent, does anyone know why?

Attached the Broker code, if necessary the Client or Worker code could provide it.

```
import * as zmq from 'zeromq'

const ipBrokerClient: string = 'tcp://*:4000'
const ipBrokerWorker: string = 'tcp://*:3000'
const idWorker: string = `worker_proxy_${process.pid}`

let frontend= zmq.socket('router'),
    backend= zmq.socket('router')

let workers: Array<string> = []

export = {

    loadFrontend(): void {
       frontend.identity = 'frontend_proxy' + process.pid
       frontend.bind(ipBrokerClient, function (err: string) {
           if (err) throw err

           console.log("Frontend in listening: " + frontend.identity)

           frontend.on('message', function (...buffer: Array<Buffer>): void {

            let idClient: Buffer = buffer[0],
                empty: Buffer = buffer[1],
                query: Buffer = buffer[2]

            let interval = setInterval(function (): void {

                if (workers.length > 0) {
                    console.log("Frontend send: " + query)

                    backend.send([workers.shift(), '', idClient, '', query])
                    clearInterval(interval)
                }

            }, 10)
        })
    })
},

    loadBackend(): void {
        backend = zmq.socket('router')
        backend.identity = 'backend_proxy' + process.pid
        backend.bind(ipBrokerWorker, function (err: string): void {
            if (err) throw err

            console.log("Backend in listening: " + backend.identity)

            backend.on('message', function (...buffer: Array<Buffer>) {
               console.log(buffer)
               let idWorker: Buffer = buffer[0],
                   empty0: Buffer = buffer[1],
                   idClient: Buffer = buffer[2],
                   empty1: Buffer = buffer[3],
                   query: Buffer = buffer[4]

               workers.push(idClient.toString())

               console.log("Worker available: " + idClient)
               frontend.send("Hello")

               if (workers[0] != "READY") {
                   frontend.send([idClient, empty0, query])
               }
           })
        })
    },

loadBroker(): void {
    this.loadFrontend()
    this.loadBackend()
  }
}
```

Excuse me if the question is not well done, I am new to the forum.

Thank you